# Join not producing results required

Tags: mysql, sql, join, toad

I want to gather all the details from a table PROD about rows containing particular triplet-sets of values. For example, I want to get all the data on the rows having columns (ID, NBR AND COP_I) with values (23534, 99, 0232) and (3423,5,09384), etc.

I was wondering about a way to select the triplets rows via a Join, which may be better than the way I am doing it below as that currently does not work.

The following Query produces the required triplets, associated with the **top 100 rows**:

```
SELECT ID, NBR, COP_I, SUM(PAD_MN) AS PAD_MN_SUMMED

FROM PROD

WHERE

PROD.FLAG = 0
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 4 DESC, 3,2,1

LIMIT 100 --TOP 100 ROWS
```

I tried joining to the Query above as follows to get all the details corresponding to those top 100 row triplets:

```
SELECT PROD.ID, PROD.NBR,PROD.COP_I,PROD.FLAG,PROD.TYPE,PROD.DATE, PROD.PAD_MN

FROM ( SELECT ID, NBR, COP_I, SUM(PAD_MN) AS PAD_MN_SUMMED

FROM PROD

WHERE

PROD.FLAG = 0
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 4 DESC, 3,2,1

LIMIT 100) TAB2
INNER JOIN PROD
ON (PROD.ID = TAB2.ID
AND PROD.NBR = TAB2.NBR
AND PROD.COP_I = TAB2.COP_I)
```

However, the above query gives me rows not even associated with any of the triplets. **I feel like I may be making a mistake with the Join, but I don't know why and how to rectify it. I get a similar issue when using the answer provided below**

**UPDATE**

PROD Table containing 10,000+ rows looks something like:

```
ID    NBR  COP_I   FLAG  TYPE     DATE        PAD_MN
3423  5    09384   0     BA       14-06-2016  18657.43
546   1098 098     1     CFA      22-03-1998  2394566.92
3423  5    09384   0     AA       28-11-2013  3423534.12
23534 99   0232    0     BA       05-01-2016  7304567.12
```

Results Required, which is to contain **only the top 100 rows information**:

```
ID    NBR  COP_I   FLAG  TYPE     DATE         PAD_MN
23534 99   0232    0     BA       05-01-2016   17370567.09
3423  5    09384   0     AA       28-11-2013   6321009.98
```

However, the output from my query gives rows, which have triplets (ID,NBR,COP_I) which are not actually outputted from the first Query above that produces the required triplets.

Comment: What table is `TRAD`? You haven't joined to it, but your join condition refers to it.

Comment: @Bohemian Sorry, I updated the query

Comment: Create a fresh sql fiddle, load up data, show expected results in tabular form

Comment: @Drew I updated the question with further information. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to remove `LIMIT 100` from your first query??? Second query is useless

Comment: create a sqlfiddle.com fiddle, share the url after loading some data. I help a number of people if they set it up on their end. I am not guessing at  datatypes and doing work others already have available but won't share

Comment: @VictorPerov I want the `LIMIT 100` so that I can get the `ID, NBR, COP_I` for the top 100 rows based on `PAD_MN_SUMMED` and the second query was to get further details of these top 100 rows. Could I ask why you say it is useless? Thanks.

Comment: if you received correct answer from me - don't forget to apply it as correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand you this is what is you want

with `join`

`select prod.* from (select id, nbr, cop_i, sum(pad_mn) as pad_mn_total from prod where prod.flag = 0 group by 1,2,3 order by 4 desc,3,2,1 limit 100) as top_prod left join prod using (id, nbr, cop_i);`

without `join`

`select prod.* from (select id, nbr, cop_i, sum(pad_mn) as pad_mn_total from prod where prod.flag = 0 group by 1,2,3 order by 4 desc,3,2,1 limit 100) as top_prod, prod where prod.id = top_prod.id and prod.nbr = top_prod.nbr and prod.cop_i = top_prod.cop_i;`

Better way is to use join. Before using queries in production mode I strongly recommend to check `explain` response for understanding how data will be collected by mysql and how your indexes works for each query.

Here you can find some info about `join` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

How to use `explain` described here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

BTW: Reading manuals is a good way to resolve problems

**UPD**: after some discussions in comments:

Q: Is there a way to prevent these "grouped" rows from being restored whilst still retrieving the other info required only for the 100 sorted rows?

A: `select sum(pad_mn) as pad_mn_total, prod.* from prod where prod.flag = 0 group by id,nbr,cop_i order by 1 desc,cop_i,nbr,id limit 100`

Comment: Thanks. But, these queries don't achieve what I am looking for. I want the query to only return the information associated with the triplets corresponding to the top 100 rows. However, I still somehow get way more than 100 rows. I gave the manuals a read, but still cant figure out where the issue lies.

Comment: Do you want to say to us in one sentence what you really want? I gave you queries that correctly works for your question: "I want the query to only return the information associated with the triplets corresponding to the top 100 rows". This queries can do it, and I've checked it before posting - All info from prod table for top 100 rows.

Comment: Yes, you have stated in the above response exactly what I want. And I understand logically that the queries you have provided should just give me the extra information in the `prod` table for the triplets associated with the top 100 rows. However, for some strange reason when I use the queries I get 100,000+ rows.

Comment: Also as `USING` as you suggested, and `ON` as I used in my query produce the same results, I don't see why your query would return different results particularly.

Comment: They do it, because you want retrieve all rows from prod that sorted by `sum(pad_mn)` and other fields right after grouping by them, doesn't it? `LIMIT 100` means in that query that it will be only 100 sorted rows but after joining prod for retrieving other info, "grouped" rows will be restored.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there a way to prevent these "grouped" rows from being restored whilst still retrieving the other info required only for the 100 sorted rows? Thank you.

Comment: `select sum(pad_mn) as pad_mn_total, prod.* from prod where prod.flag = 0 group by id,nbr,cop_i order by 1 desc,cop_i,nbr,id limit 100`

Comment: @Jojo is my last comment is appreciable for you?